# PC can not turn on

Tags: power-supply

When I played a game on my PC it turns off without warning and after that, I needed to switch PSU off and again on and PC was work again, but it was turn off again when I play the game and after that, I try again to switch PSU off and on but now when I try to turn on PC it does not turn on, just start coolers and turns off.

Comment: Can you try re-seating the CPU with new Thermal Paste. Then see if it will turn on.

Comment: I tried that, I re-seated thermal paste two days ago.

Comment: You may have a defective CPU and / or Motherboard problem. Perhaps at this point it is time to get the machine serviced.

Answer (score 0):

As @John said, you may want to do that.
It could also be an issue with the software or the bios. Maybe a power surge occurs at some point, and just wiped your whole computer. At that point, you might want to go and get your data back and fix the computer.

It could also be a loose component in the PC that is making all the trouble, like a resistor or something.

Answer (score 0):

Any time your power supply requires you to turn it off and on again to make it work, it means the internal fail-safe as has gone off.

This can go off because something from the outside causes it, ie. a surge from the network, or because something internal causes it. Most common reasons include the power supply failing internally (something is shorting or capacitors are failing) or that something in your PC's setup (motherboard, GPU, etc) is failing under stress.

Because it failed a couple of times and then doesn't turn on again, I would put my money on the actual power supply breaking.

You can try to remove as much hardware as you can, like the graphics card, any PCI-e cards, etc and try if it helps - but I doubt it.